# How to recreate checksum files in Nexus?

Tags: maven, nexus

Nexus 2.14 holds `pom.sha1` and `pom.md5` files for every pom. Due to some nasty hack I did, many of these files are outdated. Is there an easy way to recreate all checksum files for a given repository?

I thought that "Rebuild Metadata" would do the trick, but is does not recreate existing (wrong) checksum files.

Comment: Delete the old files first and afterwards you "Rebuild Metadata"...

Comment: @khmarbaise Ok, I thought there would be a solution without a recursive "remove" in the directory structure. But maybe this is the easier way.

Answer (score 0):

On v2.14.5-02, I first expired the cache for the offending `jar` GAV, then performed a "Rebuild Metadata". All the `sha1` and `md5` metadata was recreated on this date.

I had to Refresh the view to see the new metadata though.

It additionally got rid of a CI error shown below:

```sh
Could not validate integrity of download from http://nexus/path/to/repo/tld/package/artifact/version/artifact-version.pom: Checksum validation failed, no checksums available
```